Keycloak token request taking time in minutes
Keycloak 22 some token requests tokes time in minutes, and some execute very fast, what may be the reason of longer duration ?
Tried updating keycloak version, but if there is any way to reduce token request duration please share.

Turn on debug logging and check the logs. Also check the cpu usage or other important measurements. It really shouldnt take so long.

Which request takes a long time? A client_credentials Request should be fast since it can be handled in keycloak, but a grant_type=password my need some interaction with external systems (LDAP?)
